# cmake untar file only if sha has changed

Tags: cmake

I have a CMake managed project that requires a `file.tar.gz` to be downloaded and extracted. I have therefore the following in my CMakeLists.txt file

```
    set( FILE_URL "https://github.com/some_path")
    set( FILE_HASH "5beb9b7b0c882fe11ea14444cec44e9e77655f384d80b6743b1f0f82ec9a6599")

    file (DOWNLOAD "${FILE_URL}" ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/testing/file.tar.gz
          EXPECTED_HASH SHA256=${FILE_HASH})
```

I would like that a call to `make` do the following:

1. If the file does not exist and or the hash of the file doesn't match, to download it.
2. If the file has been freshly downloaded (as per 1 it didn't exist before or the hash has changed) or the extracted directory does not exist, extract it

Currently I am getting close by adding this

```
   add_custom_target(file_unpack
                    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/testing/file.tar.gz)

    add_custom_command(TARGET file_unpack
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E remove_directory ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/tests/file
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar xzf ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/testing/fire.tar.gz
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/testing/file.tar.gz
    COMMENT "Unpacking file.tar.gz"
    VERBATIM
    )
```

The problem with this approach is that it unpacks the tarball every time, even if it hasn't changed.

How can I implement both 1 and 2 above?